# View in laravel 4.0 error undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im newbie in laravel and php, im using laravel 4.0
I want to show the user profile that is already logged in via the menu view profile but there is always an error

[Undefined variable: user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHrt.png)

This is my Layout.blade.php

```
<li class="dropdown {{Request::is('users*') ? 'active' : ''}}">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile <b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
         <a href="{{ action('UserController@show', array($user->id)) }}">{{Sentry::getUser()->email}}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

This my UserController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->byId($id);


    if ($user == null || !is_numeric($id)) {
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        return \App::abort(404);
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }

    return View::make('users.show')
    ->with('user', $user);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line of your code

```
  $user =$this->user->byId($id);
```

I think it should be changed to `User::byId`. and also there need to have a function defined as `byId` in the User model. or else use eloquent functions such as `User::find($id)`

Try replacing above line with below code line

```
$user=User::find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I wrong.

Just wondering **Layout.blade.php** file. Your controller file return to **users.show** layout file. I guess that your folder structure look like

```
 /users/show.blade.php
```

Are your return to **show.blade.php** or **layout.blade.php**?